# is it safe to power off SATA HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, power-supply, sata

I have an internal SATA Harddrive connected to USB through simple SATA to USB cable: http://www.dx.com/p/cy-u3-067-sa-161-usb-3-0-to-sata-22pin-cable-sata-to-ssd-adapter-card-black-393409#.VxO-qLOrS00. But it is powered from my external ATX power supply.

The question is, could I potentially damage the HDD if I unmount the HDD, then unplug the USB a then unplug the power supply?

If so, what should I do to prevent it?

Comment: Sounds like a safe procedure to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the opinion. I have used it and today it did not start up (after powering up it started rotating, but stopped and was starting again and again), so I was thinking whether the head was not caught in the middle. After powering off and on it worked.

Comment: It happend again. I power on the HDD and it is not rotating - it just a bit scratch. Then I power it off and on and it works. I am little bit afraid of the HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to enter sleep mode via hdparm:

```
# hdparm -Y device
```

After entering sleep mode, heads are parked, spindle stopped and buffer disabled. Also, HDD needs to receive hard/soft reset, to start again. Since all drivers are off, I assume it is safe to power the HDD off.

(for further information see page 14: http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/desktop/Barracuda%207200.12/100529369h.pdf).